# Finder shows macports as file owner and file is locked

Tags: macos, osx-lion, permissions, macports

Running OSX/Lion, I have an external drive that I keep my iTunes music library on. While trying to figure out why ID3 changes to some music files (genre, etc) from within iTunes do not persist, I discovered that some of the files are locked and list 'macports' as the file owner. Odd.

I tried to run Disk Utility but "repair permissions" is disabled for the external drive. After searching around I saw some posts which suggested using the Terminal commands below to fix the permissions issue but they did not work for me.

I have used MacPorts on this machine (though usually not with this external drive connected) but found no information concerning it and permissions/file owner issues. I was able to unlock a test file and add my user account but I am unable to delete the 'macports' user.

Short of changing each file individually, is there anything else I can try?

```
sudo chflags nouchg /Volumes/volumename
sudo chmod 775 /Volumes/volumename
```

[image]

Comment: Try the `chown` command first, then `chmod`. You need to take ownership before you can reset the permissions.

Comment: @RandolphWest - that did the trick - thanks! I used 'chown -R' to traverse the entire drive. It added me as a duplicate user on some files but I suppose that won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before changing permissions with `chmod` or `chflags`, you need to take ownership of the folder using `chown`.

Something like:

```
sudo chown -R skinnytod /Volumes/volumename
```